# Move sticky block from one to another place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have sticky block on my page. It sticks to the bottom of the page, when the bottom of the viewport reaches its top. And the block must stop to be sticky before footer (when the bottom of block reaches the top of footer) and stay before footer.

The problem is in inserting block before footer: nothing happens when buttons reach footer. Why does it happen?

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <div class="block"></div>
</header>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
  position: relative;
}
.block {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}
.block-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  var blockPrimaryPosition = $(".block").offset().top; 

  function makeSticky() {
    var block = $(".block");
    var blockHeight = block.offset().top + 75; // coordinate of the bottom side of the block at any time
    var totalHeight = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(); // coordinate of the bottom of the viewport relative to the document
    if (totalHeight >= blockPrimaryPosition) {
      block.addClass("block-fixed");
    } else if (buttonsHeight >= $("footer").offset().top) {
      $("footer").before(block);
      block.removeClass("block-fixed");
    } else {
      block.removeClass("block-fixed");
    };
  };

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    makeSticky();
  });
});
```

Comment: Where you define `buttonsBlock`?

Comment: Edited, it must be "block"

Comment: I put your code in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r165daj5/). Can you update it showing the problem?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r165daj5/1/ Thanks! When black block reaches footer, it must stay above it.